скомпилировать exe в самодостаточный
не могу скомпилировать exe в самодостаточный, использую wpf и .net 8, проблема в том, что без файлов wpfgfx_cor3.dll, D3DCompiler_47_cor3.dll, PresentationNative_cor3.dll, которые копируются в выходную директорию после опубликования проекта, exe не запускается, они обязательно должны присутствовать в одной директории, а мне нужен лишь 1 exe файл. При этом других зависимостей у меня в проекте нету.
Я пытался делать через dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained, пробовал добавлять эти 3 файла в сам проект и делать их внедряемыми ресурсами, так же опубликовывал встроенным способом, перетыкал вообще всё, автономную публикацию и так далее. Проблема не решилась

@aepot: Но ТС говорит, что у него с WPF трюк не проходит. Вроде я слыхал краем уха, что там и правда возможны проблемы.

А с дополнительными тремя файлами всё работает?

У меня давно, кажется на .NET 5, работало и с WPF.

@VladD <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract> --> .csproj, об этом сказано по ссылка, которую я дал выше

@aepot: А, вот в чём была проблема. Это тонкость, конечно.
